# jQuery Table row toggle show/hide associated with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need a little help with jQuery and HTML(table).

Pls take a look at my jsfiddle page to see what I am gonna try to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/U25EK/

Each TD contains certain value (from 01 to 06) and has CLASS name which is related to its value and the lists of buttons above the TABLE.
When the page initially loaded, all those buttons are enabled that means all TABLE DATA are visible.

When I click to turn on/off the button, i want jQuery to observe ON/OFF status of buttons and if the status matches to the values of each table row, i want jQuery to toggleSlide(show/hide) TABLE ROW.
(sorry about my poor english and explanation...)

For example, if I turn off button01 the row1 will be hidden. Then I turn button4 and button6 off, the row5 will be hidden. And so on or vice versa...

HTML:

```
<ul id="listBtns">
<li><a href="#" class="on">01</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="on">02</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="on">03</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="on">04</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="on">05</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="on">06</a></li>
</ul>

<table id="tblResult">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>01</th>
        <th>02</th>
        <th>03</th>
        <th>04</th>
        <th>05</th>
        <th>06</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>row1</th>
        <td class="val01">01</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row2</th>
        <td class="val01">01</td>
        <td class="val02">02</td>
        <td class="val03">03</td>
        <td class="val04">04</td>
        <td class="val05">05</td>
        <td class="val06">06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row3</th>
        <td class="val03">03</td>
        <td class="val05">05</td>
        <td class="val04">04</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row4</th>
        <td class="val02">02</td>
        <td class="val04">04</td>
        <td class="val05">05</td>
        <td class="val06">06</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row5</th>
        <td class="val04">04</td>
        <td class="val06">06</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row6</th>
        <td class="val03">03</td>
        <td class="val02">02</td>
        <td class="val04">04</td>
        <td class="val06">06</td>
        <td class="val05">05</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#listBtns a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    //and some function continues...
});
```

I am kinda stack and only can come up with very poor and inefficient codes(that perhaps might not work completely...) and I dont know which jQuery selector to use. please help me out.

Thanx.

Comment: Instead of this `if( $(this).hasClass('on') ) {
        $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('off on');
    }` you can simply use `$(this).toggleClass('on off');`

Comment: @PalashMondal Yes thats very nice of you to let me know that. I fixed it ;) Thanx

Answer (score 7):

Need one line only --

```
$(function() {
    $('#listBtns a').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('on off');        
       $("#tblResult tr").eq($(this).text()).toggle('on off');
    });
});
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EWnmL/1/)

This will work as long as text and row number matches.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have explained more. each buttons are not related to TABLE ROW but TABLE DATA. so if I turned off button01 only row1 will disappear. Then I continue to turn off button03, 05, 04, the row3 will disappear. So in my jsfiddle example, the time row2 will disappear when all buttons are turned off. I hope that explains.

Comment: What if `row2` does not contain `01 to 06` ie all numbers? In that case as well you want to hide it?

Comment: This example is a cutout from my proj. According to the specification every table row has at least one value.

Comment: @norixxx interesting. I'll try to answer that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some thing like below, give an id to your table like "my_table" so that in case of multiple table s in a page it will affect only specific table. and by using 2,3 you can refer row number #2 and #3 should be hide and #4, #5 means row number #4 and #5 should be
display.

```
     $("#my_table tr:nth-child(2)").hide();
     $("#my_table tr:nth-child(3)").hide();

     $("#my_table tr:nth-child(4)").show();
     $("#my_table tr:nth-child(5)").show();
```

Call it on click event of any thing and check.